# Tax taking out pension exceptional circumstances (UK)

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, pension

I used to live overseas where I had a private pension pot. Due to covid19 exceptional circumstamnces, the country has allowed to take out 25% which I've just received in my UK bank account. How this should be taxed?

Comment: To many potential complications to make an answer, but from [this GOV.UK page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/pension-tax-for-overseas-pensions-additional-information/pension-tax-for-overseas-pensions-additional-information#lump-sums-from-pensions-held-overseas) it looks like that from 2017 you pay tax on 100% of a foreign pension (90% before that date)... if the lump sum was _built-up_ before April 2017, it will receive "_former tax treatment_" (whatever that was).

Comment: Whether any of this changes because of Covid-19, I don't know...I've not dug into it, but the only tax-related changes I seem to remember hearing about involve possibly being able to _defer_ tax payments, but even that half-remembered nugget may be wrong